# Show that set $K=\{1,4,9,16,25,...\}$ is infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is **my try**:

We denote $$f:\mathbb{N}\to K$$
$$f(x) = x^2$$
I must prove that this function is bijective , but that isnt! This is why :
$$y=x^2\Rightarrow x=\pm\sqrt{y}\notin N$$
So $f$ is not surjective and thus not bijective.

Can anybody define better function for this problem?

Comment: If $N$ is to be the natural numbers (without $0$), your function certainly is bijective.

Comment: @Randall how about $-\sqrt{y}$? thats completely negative .

Comment: That is not in your domain, so who cares?  Review carefully the definition of surjective.

Comment: @Randall So if x equals only the negative thing , we can say that isn't surjective . and in this example we contain positive or negative and that is the reason why my function is surjective?

Comment: Your inverse function isn't a map $g:K\to\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$, it's a map $g:K\to\mathbb{N}$, so negative square roots don't even come into it. If you want a precise proof for the surjectivity of $f$ then just choose $k\in K$ and $\sqrt{k}\in\mathbb{N}$, then $f(\sqrt{k}) = \sqrt{k}^2 = k$, hence it's surjective.

Comment: Again, review the definition of surjective.  If $f: X \to Y$ is your function, the definition of surjective says to each $b \in Y$ there is an $a \in X$--not an $a$ from anywhere in the universe--for which $f(a)=b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't take the negative values ${-\sqrt{y}}$ here. It's clear ${x=\sqrt{y}}$ is your inverse function from ${K\to \mathbb{N}}$. When people say ${y=x^2 \Rightarrow x=\pm \sqrt{y}}$, they are finding the solutions to an equation. This is not what you are doing, you are finding the inverse function, and from context it is obvious that we are not bothered at all about the negative solutions.

If you need anymore clarification, leave a comment and I'll be happy to add a bit more!

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in \mathbb N$ then $x \in \mathbb N$ and we must remember that.

So you you are told "$y = x^2$ now solve for $x$" then you have $x = \sqrt y$ and even though $-x= -\sqrt{y}$ also solves it, it isn't the solution we *want*.  We only want the positive.

.... But we aren't actually being asked to solve $y = x^2$.

We are being asked to solve "$y = x^2$ now solve for $x$".  You are being asked to "show that for every element in $y \in K$ there exists an element $x \in \mathbb N$ so that $f(x) = x^2 = y$".  That's a subtly different question but the subtlety makes it a *very* different question.

And as $K$ is *defined* so that .... actually you *haven't* defined $K$ at all... and that *must* be done for this question to actually make any sense.... but is strongly *implied* that the definition of $K$ is:

$K = \{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, ....\}$

$=\{1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2, 5^2, ....\}$

$= \{n^2|$ for all natural numbers $n\}$.

And if $y \in K$ then *by definition* we must have $y = n^2$ for some natural number $n$.  So to find an $x\in \mathbb N$ so that $f(x) = x^2 = y = n^2$ we just let $x = n$.

And the function $f$ certainly *is* onto.

=====

To be utterly thorough for the sake of hammering home the concept.

To prove $f:\mathbb N \to K=\{1,4,9,.....\}$ is bijective we must prove

1: It is surjective.  well, I did that, but just to repeat.  That means:

> For every $y \in K$ there exists an $x \in \mathbb N$ so that $f(x) = y$.

That is clearly true as if $y \in K$ then $y = n^2$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$ so $f(n) = n^2 = y$ and so thats that.

2: It is injective:  That is to say for every every $y \in K$ there is at most only one $x \in \mathbb N$ so that $f(x) = y$.

This is straight forward.  If $y \in K$ then $y = n^2$ for some natural $n$.  If $x\in \mathbb N$ and $f(x) = x^2 = y = n^2$ then we must have (as you said) the $x = \pm \sqrt {n^2}  =\pm n$.  But as $x \in \mathbb N$ we must have $x =n$ and that is the only possible solution in $\mathbb N$.

So it is injective.